Doval and Skreta (2022): Mechanism Design with Limited Commitment. Why Would the Principal's Beliefs Depend on the Public Randomisation?
In Doval and Skreta (2022; Mechanism Design with Limited Commitment; Econometrica), they prove a revelation principle in a dynamic setting where the principal only has limited commitment, i.e., in cases where the Myersonian revelation principle need not apply. I am confused by a section of the online appendix where they formalise the principal's beliefs.

Background & Notation
To clear up some background details, there is a single agent and a single principal who interact over $T\leq \infty $ periods in discrete time. The agent has persistent private information in the form of a type $\theta \in \Theta$ which is unknown by the principal, but there is a common prior of $\mu_1\in \Delta(\Theta)$. In each period, the principal and agent interact, leading to an allocation $a\in A$. Let $A^t=(a_1,\dots , a_t)$ be the set of implemented allocations through period $t$. The set of possible allocations may change depending on previous allocations, and the space of allocations available at time $t$ is determined by a correspondence $\mathcal{A}_t:A^{t-1}\rightrightarrows A$ which for any $a_{t-1}\in A^{t-1}$ maps to a measurable subset $\mathcal{A}_t(a_{t-1})\subset A$. The allocation in a given period is determined by a mechanism $\boldsymbol{M}_t=(M^{\boldsymbol{M}_t},S^{\boldsymbol{M}_t},\phi^{\boldsymbol{M}_t})$, where $M^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}$ are the input messages the agent can send which cannot be contracted on, $S^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}$ are the output messages which can be contracted on, and $\phi^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}$ is a measurable mapping $M^{\boldsymbol{M}_t} \owns m \mapsto \phi(m) \in \Delta(S^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}\times A_t)$. The principal's problem is a mechanism-selection game. Suppose the principal can choose mechanisms based on a collection of input-output message spaces, indexed by $\mathcal{I}$: $\{(M_i,S_i)\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$. The "canonical" input-output space $(\Theta, \Delta(\Theta)$ is assumed to be included in this collection. The principal is unable to commit credibly to not reneging on earlier agreements as it learns more about the agent's information. The principal's lack of credible commitment is what precludes the use of the classical revelation principle.
At the beginning of each period, $t$, both agents observe the realisation of a public randomisation device, $\omega \sim U[0,1]$. Define $\Omega=[0,1]$. The principal then offers the agent a mechanism $\boldsymbol{M}_t$, with the property that for all $m\in M^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}, \phi^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}(S^{\boldsymbol{M}_t},\mathcal{A}_t(a_{t-1})\vert m)=1$. The agent, having observed the mechanism, either participates in the mechanism $(\pi =1)$ or not $(\pi =0)$. If they do not participate, an outside option allocation, $a*$ is implemented and the game proceeds to $t+1$. Instead, if they participate, they send a message $m\in M^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}$, which is unobserved by the principal. An output message and allocation $(s_t,a_t)$ are drawn according to $\phi^{\boldsymbol{M}_t}(\cdot\vert m)$. Both the output message and allocation are observed by the agent and principal and the game continues to $t+1$.
The public histories of the game capture what the principal knows through period $t$: the past realisations of the public randomisation device, past mechanism choices, the agent's participation decisions, and the realised output messages and allocation. Let $h^t$ denote a public history through period $t$ and let $H^t$ denote the set of all such histories. A private history instead captures what the agent knows. The agent knows the public history, along with what input messages they sent into the mechanism and also their private information about their type. Let $h_A^t$ denote the agent's history through period $t$ and $H_A^t(h^t)$ denote the set of private histories which are consistent with public history $h_t$. Therefore, $\Theta \times H_A^t(h_t)$ denotes the set of private histories consistent with public history $h_t$.
The principal is uncertain about the agent's payoff-relevant type $\theta$ and the agent history, $h_A^t$. Thus, a belief for the principal in period $t$ at public history $h_t$ is a distribution $\mu_t(h^t)\in \Delta (\Theta \times H_A^t(h^t))$.

Question
In the online appendix, Doval and Skreta formally show that the principal's beliefs at $t+1$ can be viewed as a measurable function from $H^{t+1}$ to $\Delta(\Theta\times H_A^{t+1})$. As a part of this, they show that almost surely, the beliefs of the principal at time $t+1$ do not depend on the realisation of the public randomisation device at time $t+1$. They take a formal argument to show this point and I am missing why such a formal argument is needed. I'll briefly outline my understanding of their argument.
First, for a given strategy by the agent at time $t$, they define a transition probability $\mathbb{P}_-^{t+1}$ from $\Delta(\Theta \times H_A^t)\times \mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{I}}$ to $\Theta \times H_{A-}^{t+1}$, where, with $\mathcal{M}_{i,j}=\{\phi :M_i\to \Delta (S_j\times A)| \phi \text{ measurable}\}$, $H_{A-}^{t+1}=H_A^t\times \cup_{i,j\in \mathcal{I}}(\mathcal{M}_{i,j}\times S_j \times (A\cup \{\emptyset\}) )$ is the collection of private "continuation" histories. That is, $h_{A-}^{t+1}=(h_A^t,\boldsymbol{M}_t,s_t,a_t)\in H_{A-}^{t+1}$ is the private history produced by picking mechanism $\boldsymbol{M}_t$ at time $t$, and output message and allocation $(s_t,a_t)$ being subsequently realised after the agent plays according to their strategy. Likewise, $H_{-}^{t+1}=H^t\times \cup_{i,j\in \mathcal{I}}(\mathcal{M}_{i,j}\times M_i \times S_j \times (A\cup \{\emptyset\}) )$ is the public continuation history. This transition probability $\mathbb{P}_-^{t+1}$ represents the distribution over private continuation histories given the principal's time $t$ belief and choice of mechanism.
Second, the principal updates their belief over $\Theta \times H_A^{t+1}$ by conditioning $\mathbb{P}_-^{t+1}$ on the realised public continuation history $h_-^{t+1}\in H_-^{t+1}$ (formally, the updated belief $\mu_{t+1}$ is the disintegration of $\mathbb{P}_-^{t+1}$ by $\text{proj}_{H_-^{t+1}}$). A theorem from Pollard (2002; A user's guide to measure theoretic probability theory) then proves that $\mu_{t+1}$ is a measurable mapping from $H_{-}^{t+1}$ to $\Delta(\Theta \times H_{A-}^{t+1})$.
Third, they show that the following equation holds on page 6 of the online appendix.
$$\int_{\text{proj}_{H_-^{t+1}}\tilde{\Theta}\times\tilde{H}_{A-}^{t+1}}\int_{\tilde{\Omega}}\begin{bmatrix}\mu_{t+1}'(\tilde{\Theta}\times\tilde{H}_{A-}^{t+1}\times\tilde{\Omega}\vert h_-^{t+1},\omega')\\ -\mu_{t+1}(\tilde{\Theta}\times\tilde{H}_{A-}^{t+1}\vert h_-^{t+1})\end{bmatrix}l(d\omega')v_{t+1}(dh_-^{t+1}\vert \mu_t(h^t),\boldsymbol{M}_t)=0 \qquad (\dagger)$$
In the above, the measure $l$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Tildes represent arbitrary measurable sets in the associated spaces. The measure $v_{t+1}(\mu(h^t),\boldsymbol{M}_t)$ is a probability distribution over the public continuation histories given the principal's belief and choice of mechanism (the public-history analogue of $\mathbb{P}_-^{t+1}$).
From $(\dagger)$ they conclude that $\mu_{t+1}$ is $v_{t+1}(\mu(h^t),\boldsymbol{M}_t)$-almost surely independent of the realisation of the public randomisation device at time $t+1$. From this, they state the principal's $t+1$ belief can be viewed as a measurable mapping from $H^{t+1}$ to $\Delta(\Theta \times H_A^{t+1})$. I think this is because we already had that the belief $\mu_{t+1}$ was a measurable mapping from $H_{-}^{t+1}$ to $\Delta(\Theta \times H_{A-}^{t+1})$ and since it is independent of the randomisation device, we can move from the continuation histories ($H_-^{t+1}$ and $H_{A-}^{t+1}$) to the period $t+1$ histories ($H^{t+1}$ and $H_A^{t+1}$) which additionally include the $t+1$ realisation of the public randomisation.
My confusion is that this fourth step seems somewhat obvious and I cannot tell why it needs to be proved beyond a one-line statement. Specifically, since the public randomisation device at $t+1$ is independent of previous events, does it not immediately follow that it cannot signal something about the agent's type or private history? Is there something deeper going on that I am missing which their exposition demonstrates? Why would the principal's period-$t+1$ beliefs be influenced by the realisation of the $t+1$-period public randomisation?
